# How to post dynamically generated vuejs array to mysql database

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-5.4

I am using this code in my LARAVEL project

http://jsfiddle.net/teepluss/12wqxxL3/

Items are dynamically generated in the cart_items array.

I want to know how to loop over the generated items and post this to the database or how to pass this to the controller and save it from there.

How should i go about doing that

Here is my script

```
var app = new Vue({

http: {
  root: '/root',
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('value')
  }
},

el: '#wrapper',
data: {
    cart_items: [],
},

created() {

    this.$http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/ice', function(ice) {
    //console.log(ice);
    this.articles = ice;
}.bind(this));

    },

        computed: {
            count: function() {
                return this.cart_items.length;
            },
            total: function() {
                return _.reduce(this.cart_items, function(n, cart_item) {
                    return cart_item.price * cart_item.qty + n;
                }, 0).toFixed(2);
            },

            filteredArticles: function() {
            var articles_array = this.articles,
                searchString = this.searchString;


            if (!searchString) {
                return articles_array;
            }

            searchString = searchString.trim().toLowerCase();

            articles_array = articles_array.filter(function(item) {
                if (item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
                    return item;
                }
            })

            return articles_array;;
        }

        },
        methods: {

            notInCart: function(article) {
                var ids = _.pluck(this.cart_items, 'id');
              return !_.contains(ids, article.id);
            },

            addToCart: function(product) {
            var cart = Vue.util.extend({}, product);
            var ids = _.pluck(this.cart_items, 'id');

                    if (!_.contains(ids, product.id)) {
              cart.qty = 1;       
                        this.cart_items.push(cart);
                    }
            },


            addQty: function(product) {
                product.qty = product.qty +1;
            },

            decQty: function(product) {
                product.qty -= 1;
                if (product.qty <= 0) {
                    this.cart_items.$remove(product);
                }
            },

            clearall:function(){
                 this.cart_items = [];
            },

            UserOrder: function(){
                 var order = this.cart_items;
                 var output = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(order));
                 // I am able to see the output in the dev console here
                // How should go about posting this to the mysql database. 
                 console.log(output);          
            }

        }
    });
```

Also here is project settings

Laravel - 5.4 
vue     - 1.0.12 
vue resource - 0.1.17

I am new to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just want to post it?

```
methods: {
  ...
  postData: function() {
    this.http.post('your/endpoint', { items: this.cart_items })
      .then( (response) => { // your server response } )
      .catch( (error) => { // error callback } )
  }
  ...
```

This will post to your api endpoint so to the laravel controller from there loop through the `$request->get('items')` and persist it to DB.

Comment: Hello, thanx for your reply.
I tried your code, I am getting the following error
FatalThrowableError in Grammar.php line 135:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in D:\bitbucket\money\6df\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 681

here is my controller 
public function order(Request $request){

     $order = new Order();
        $order->orders = $request->get('items');
        $order->save();
}

Comment: I want to post and retrieve as well

Comment: This I can't help you with as I would have to know a lot more about db design and model relations. I'm sorry. But at least you know the vue part is correct. Good luck.